# __cxa_throw in fontWithName:size:

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uifont

I have a function to get the Helvetica Neue font on iOS 8.3 (though I've had the same problem since ~8.0).

```
static UIFont *helveticaNeue() {
  return [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue"
                     size:[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom  == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 30 : 24];
}
```

This function actually functions perfectly, but the first time it is called, the debugger stops, with the callstack after this function looking like `__objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache` -> `__cxa_throw`.

Judging by some other questions I've read, this exception is harmless. However, it is *really* annoying to have to hit continue every time it is hit.

I've tried various synonymous `UIFont` functions to try to get a Helvetica Neue `UIFont` object, or making this a class or instance method, and all of them throw this exception.

I've read that I can prevent this from being hit by changing my All Exceptions Breakpoint to be just Objective-C exceptions, however I don't want to do this, because this project contains a large amount of C++ code, and it seems like this would prevent exception breaks in this code.

Does anyone know how to prevent the exception from being thrown, or how to ignore just this one specific exception?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my app had a framework whose info.plist file listed a provided font that was also listed as a provided font by the app itself (in the Fonts provided by application). Removing the duplicate fixed this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer yet, but it has got me looking in the right direction.